# How to disable text correction suggestions (underlined) with Google Voice typing?

Tags: voice-recognition, gboard, text-input

When I use Google Voice typing to produce some text, a fair amount of the text becomes underlined (and if you tap the underlined text a drop-down list presents suggestions to correct any errors in the voice recognition). However, this functionality makes it very cumbersome to manually edit the text with the keyboard (I find that I have to first tap the underlined text, then choose delete and rewrite the entire snippet of text again). Moreover I find that most often the suggested corrections are incorrect, so they are not helpful.

I'd much rather turn these corrections off if it was possible, and simply edit any errors manually with the keyboard. Can it be done? Thanks.

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer to this problem. The drop-down list of spelling and grammar suggestions that appears from Google's voice typing text correction/suggestions covers up the actual suggested corrections (in the horizontal strip based on keyboard settings) that I would like to use, when I tap into a word that has been underlined. There does not appear to be any setting for turning off Google voice-typing text correction/suggestions. The text correction/suggestions settings in the Android keyboard(s) settings have no effect on it, and there is no setting for it in the Google Voice Typ

Answer (score 0):

The best work-around I have found is this:

Tap on the (underlined) word you are interested in changing.
When the (unwanted) suggestion box appears, tap someplace *outside of the box*.
The box will disappear but the cursor will remain where you originally tapped. 
Now you can either start typing, or deleting, or you can click on a suggestion from the regular suggestion strip below.

Hope this helps.